# List files in directory, store output in file then count lines in output

Tags: unix

I am a beginner in unix and have been given the following task:

List the contents of your home directory, store this output in a file called newHomelist and then count the lines of this output.

First I checked what my result should be:

```
ls ~/ | wc -l
```

I get the result '20' from this.

I have then attempted the following:

```
ls ~/ > newHomelist | wc -l
```

However this gives me the result of '0'. I think I understand why it is doing that, as I have moved all the lines inside the file and it is therefore not counting anything. I guess that I need to go into the file and then count the lines. Something like this:

```
 ls ~/ > newHomelist | more newHomelist | wc -l
```

However the result I get is '23'. This isn't the result that I was expecting. Is anyone able to tell me where I am going wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Does the task state that you need to do this with a single command? What about using several commands, separated by a semicolon (or newline)? BTW, `more` is interactive and adds more lines, so the number of lines increases.

Comment: It doesn't, though it falls under a section called 'redirection and piping' and I assumed that it should be done with one command. With your advice I have tried the following:
    ls ~/  > newHomelist ; more newHomelist | wc -l
This has given me the correct output of '20' so I am happy with this result, thank you. I will now read up on what you mean by 'more is interactive'.

Comment: A program is called *interactive* if it expects user input (and usually prints output in response). `more` is a pager that allows to browse large files. It prints a prompt named `--More--` at the bottom line of the screen if there is more to show, hence its name. Try `more sometextfile` to see it. Then type `h` for help at the `--More--` prompt. That's the user input `more` will react to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to do it in a one-liner you can split the output (stdout) by using `tee` (see 'man tee')

```
$ ls ~/ | tee newHomelist | wc -l
```

Redirecting stdout onto a file using `>` means it is not available for later commands in a pipeline.

You could do it as multiple commands also

```
$ ls ~/ > newHomeList
$ wc -l newHomeList
  # or the two commands combined onto one line as
$ ls ~/ > newHomeList ; wc -l newHomeList
```

Comment: Thank you. This has helped me. I now understand what 'tee' does. :)